# How to move a whole div to the right side

Tags: html, css

How do I move a whole div element to the right side? At present both div:s are appearing side by side. Please see the image I provided, I want to make it work like that.

Please help me with this. Thanks in Advance

[image: sample Image]

```html
<div class="d-flex align-items-start summary" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">

                <img [src]="imagePath" style="width: 150px;max-height: 150px;clip-path: square(22px at center);" class="mr-3 d-none d-sm-block"
                    alt="...">

                <i (click)="inputFile.click()" *ngIf="isEditItems" style="color : white;left: 155px; 
                    position: absolute; top: 28px; padding: 3px; background-color: rgb(0, 195, 255); 
                    border-radius: 50%;font-size: 12px;"
                    class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>

                <div>
                     
                        <div class="col-sm">
                                <div class="office-address-heading">
                                    <b>Office Address</b>
                                </div>
                                <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                                    <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-2x mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <address class="mb-0">
                                        {{myprofile?.OfficeAddress}}
                                    </address>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <hr />
                            <div class="col-sm">
                                <div class="office-address-heading">
                                    <b>Communication Details</b>
                                </div>
                                <div class="d-flex align-items-center office-address-details">
                                    <i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <div><a href="tel:1-562-867-5309">{{myprofile?.Phone}}</a></div>
                    
                                    <span class="d-flex align-items-center mail office-address-details">
                                        <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        <div>
                                            <a href="mailto:rafael.cepeda@lpl.com">{{myprofile?.Email}}</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                   
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Use `float:right` css

Comment: You say "both divs", but there are 10 divs in the code.

Comment: Hi @Sumesh TG ...Yes I did that one but Its not working, Can you tell me for which div I ahve to use that one?

Comment: I have added the answer with the code please refer that .

Comment: Hi @Lister... Image div should be left side and Office address Div should be right side...But both are coming side by side PLZ check the Image I provided , can you please  help me in this,

Comment: Hi sundeep i hope my answer was helpful is there anything else i can help you with .?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go please use this

```css
.d-flex.align-items-start.summary {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
  justify-content:space-between;
  margin:auto;
  max-width:1170px;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex align-items-start summary" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">

                <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/147/147144.svg" style="width: 150px;max-height: 150px;clip-path: square(22px at center);" class="mr-3 d-none d-sm-block"
                    alt="...">

                <i (click)="inputFile.click()" *ngIf="isEditItems" style="color : white;left: 155px; 
                    position: absolute; top: 28px; padding: 3px; background-color: rgb(0, 195, 255); 
                    border-radius: 50%;font-size: 12px;"
                    class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>

                <div>
                     
                        <div class="col-sm">
                                <div class="office-address-heading">
                                    <b>Office Address</b>
                                </div>
                                <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                                    <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-2x mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <address class="mb-0">
                                        {{myprofile?.OfficeAddress}}
                                    </address>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <hr />
                            <div class="col-sm">
                                <div class="office-address-heading">
                                    <b>Communication Details</b>
                                </div>
                                <div class="d-flex align-items-center office-address-details">
                                    <i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <div><a href="tel:1-562-867-5309">{{myprofile?.Phone}}</a></div>
                    
                                    <span class="d-flex align-items-center mail office-address-details">
                                        <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        <div>
                                            <a href="mailto:rafael.cepeda@lpl.com">{{myprofile?.Email}}</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                   
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Sundeep i just wanna tell you that for the mobile screen responsiveness you only have to add this in the media query. .d-flex.align-items-start.summary {
  
 flex-direction:Column ;
   
} so for small screen they will appear below each other and will be 100% responsive too.

Comment: Thanks For the help   @Sumit

Comment: Always welcome.please let me know if you want any kind of help .

Comment: Hi @sumit Can you Check this link once, I am facing some problem can You Please help in that,  Here is the   LINK : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53812237/when-i-zoom-the-page-or-giving-more-text-text-is-coming-out-of-the-box-and-ima

Comment: Sure please le me take a look

Comment: can you provid me the live link of this site ?

Comment: Hi @ sumit Its some what confidental So thatz the reason I am unable to give live link

Comment: No worries i have added the answer to you question please take a look.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53812237/when-i-zoom-the-page-or-giving-more-text-text-is-coming-out-of-the-box-and-ima