# When I Zoom the page or Giving more text , Text is coming out of the box and Image icons are not properly Aligned

Tags: html, css

When I Zoom the page Giving more text , Text is coming out of the box and Image icons are moving out.I am putting two screen shots, 1st Image is  what I am getting the output after coding the below code and 
2nd Image  is excepted output  [image: This is what I am getting after coding....[![Sample Picture]
    Please help me in this Thanks in advance

```css
This is Css code,When I Zoom the page, Text is coming out of the box and Image icons are moving out.

.flex-container{
    display: flex;
    overflow-x:auto;
}


.officeflex{
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
}


hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.d-flex.align-items-start.summary {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
  justify-content:space-between;
  margin:auto;
  max-width:1170px;
  width:100%;
}

.align-items-center{
  .size{
    font-size: 12px;
   }
}
.office-address-heading{

    .Address{
        color:grey;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}

.office-address-details{
    .mr-2{
        color: rgb(0, 195, 255); font-size: 20px
    }
}

.profile-details{
    margin-left:15px;
    padding:40px;

    .name{
        font-size:12px;
        line-height:22px;
        font-weight: 500;
    }

    .designation{
        font-size:12px;
        line-height:25px;
        font-weight: 400;
    }

    .phone{
        font-size:12px;
        font-weight: 100;
    }
}
.btn{
    font-size: 12px  !important;
    background-color: #0076C8;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
This is HTML code,When I Zoom the page, Text is coming out of the box and Image icons are moving out.
<div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="profile-summary">
                    <b>Profile summary</b>
                </div>

                <div class="d-flex align-items-start summary1" style="margin-bottom: 10px;background-color: #fff;">

                    <app-image [imagesrc]="imagePath" style="width: 150px;max-height: 150px;clip-path: square(22px at center);"
                        class="col-2 mr-3 d-none d-sm-block" alt="..."></app-image>

                    <i (click)="inputFile.click()"  style="color : white;left: 165px; 
                    position: absolute; top: 28px; padding: 3px; background-color: rgb(0, 195, 255); 
                    border-radius: 50%;font-size: 12px;"
                        class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <div class="col-5 profile-details">

                            <div class="col-sm">
                            
                                    <span class="name">
                                        <b style = "color: rgb(25,25,112); font-size : 15px ">{{myprofile?.FirstName}}  {{myprofile?.LastName}}</b>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                      
                                <div class="col-sm">
                            
                                        <span class="name">
                                            <p>{{myprofile?.Role}} </p>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>

                                <div class="col-sm">
                            
                                        <span class="name">
                                            <p>{{myprofile?.Phone}}  {{myprofile?.UserName}}</p>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>

                    </div>

                    <div>

                        <div class="col-12 ">
                            <div class="office-address-heading">
                                <p class="Address">Office Address</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                                <!-- <i style="color:grey;" class="fa fa-map-marker fa-2x mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i> -->
                                <address class="mb-0 size">
                                    {{myprofile?.OfficeAddress}}
                                </address>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr />
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <div class="office-address-heading">
                                <p class="Address">Communication Details</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-flex align-items-center office-address-details">
                                <i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <div><a style="color: black;" href="tel:1-562-867-5309">{{myprofile?.Phone}}</a></div>

                                <span class="d-flex align-items-center mail office-address-details">
                                    <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <div>
                                        <a style="color: black;" href="mailto:rafael.cepeda@lpl.com">{{myprofile?.Email}}</a>
                                    </div>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
              

            </div>
        </div>
```

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qc2ci.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYK1a.png
```

Comment: please provide me the live link to this page

Comment: You should remove the oferflow-x :auto; i think it is going out side of the div because you are using overflow-x and it is overflowing to the x-Axis .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the image and the icon take an outer div to your image and the icon. and apply this css to them .

```css
.outer-div-for-the-imgae-icon{position:relative; display:block; height:300px; width:300px;  }

.outer-div-for-the-imgae-icon img{height:100%; width:100%; object-fit:cover;}

.outer-div-for-the-imgae-icon i{position:absolute; top:0; left:100%; font-size:40px; color:green; }
```

```html
<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"></head>


<div class="outer-div-for-the-imgae-icon">

<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/220453/pexels-photo-220453.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940"/>

<i class="fa fa-check-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>


</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Sumit Thanks a lot Its working for Image... But Text is moving out of the box

Comment: let me take a look

Comment: instead of using max-width:1170px; just use width:100%; and let me know the result

Comment: Hi @Sumit , Yes it working Thanks a lot.....But for Communications Details I need to write media Query.. There I am facing Issue , IF you don'tmine, Can you check this link ,  Here is the LINK : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53827818/need-to-write-media-qurey-in-css-beacuse-when-i-zoom-my-page-its-overlapping-wi

Comment: Your welcome Please feel free to ask if you will have any query in future.

Comment: Hi @Sumit , Yes it working Thanks a lot.....But for Communications Details I need to write media Query.. There I am facing Issue , IF you don'tmine, Can you check this link ,  Here is the LINK : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53827818/need-to-write-media-qurey-in-css-beacuse-when-i-zoom-my-page-its-overlapping-wi

Comment: Hi @Sumit, With your help I fix all my code Issues , Thanks for your help  But one thing is pending,If you dont mine can you help me in that.. ..Here is the LINK : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53834067/fix-a-problem-for-text-overlapping-on-image-while-zooming                   problem is from this div : “ col-6 pad float right”. In this div I have given 3 attributes(Name, phone number) As you can see in that Image . So that values are overlapping with image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185460/discussion-between-sundeep-and-sumit-kumar).

Comment: Hi @Sumit, I am facing some issue while I am zooming the page.. If you dont mine can you help me that?

Comment: Hi @Sumit, Here is the Link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53928523/alignment-issue-with-zoom