# Fix a problem for text overlapping on Image while zooming

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

While zooming the page TEXT is overlapping with the Image, I am sharing my screenshot, Please look into that and can you please give me the solution.
Thanks in Advance...[image]

This is the css Code, While zooming the page TEXT is overlapping with the Image,

```
.Pad{
    padding: 60px 0px;
    margin-top: -300px;
 }

 body {
    margin: 0;
}

.outer-div-for-the-imgae-icon{position:relative; display:block; height:300px; width:300px;   }

.outer-div-for-the-imgae-icon img{height:300px; width:300px; object-fit:cover;}

.outer-div-for-the-imgae-icon i{position:absolute; top:0; left:100%; font-size:40px;}
```

This is the HTML code, While zooming the page TEXT is overlapping with the Image,

```
<div class="col-12 col-12 p-0">
                        <div class="col-6 float-left">
                            <div class="outer-div-for-the-imgae-icon">
                                <app-image [imagesrc]="imagePath" style="width: 190px;max-height: 190px;clip-path: square(25px at center);"
                                    class="d-none d-sm-block" alt="..."></app-image>
                                <i (click)="inputFile.click()" style="color : white;left: 180px; 
                                position: absolute; top: -5px; padding: 3px; background-color: rgb(0, 195, 255); 
                                border-radius: 50%;font-size: 12px;"
                                    class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-6 Pad float-right">
                                <div class="col-sm ">

                                    <span class="name">
                                        <b style="color: rgb(25,25,112); font-size : 15px ">{{myprofile?.FirstName}}
                                            {{myprofile?.LastName}}</b>
                                    </span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm">

                                    <span class="name">
                                        <p>{{myprofile?.Role}}</p>
                                    </span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm">

                                    <span class="name">
                                        <p>{{myprofile?.Phone}} {{myprofile?.UserName}}</p>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>





        <!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: are you creating a custom zoom functionality in javascript or just using the default browser zoom feature ?

Comment: Just using default browser zoom... Can you please help me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi sandeep please try this and replace this css in you css and let me know if its fine.please adjust the min  and max width and height according to you.

`.outer-div-for-the-imgae-icon{position:relative; display:block; min-height:300px; width:100%; height:auto;} .outer-div-for-the-imgae-icon img{max-height:300px; width:100%; max-width:300px; height:auto;   object-fit:cover;}  .outer-div-for-the-imgae-icon i{position:absolute; top:0; left:100%; font-size:40px;}`

I think this is overlapping only because we have given the image a fixed width and height .

Comment: have you removed your inline css for the image ?

Comment: i mean in the html       <app-image [imagesrc]="imagePath" style="width: 190px;max-height: 190px;clip-path: square(25px at center);"
                                    class="d-none d-sm-block" alt="..."></app-image>    have you removed this width and height of image ?

Comment: Oh Your asking to remove whole Style in HTML?

Comment: Not the whole but for the image section which i just posted on the above commment . you must remove this css from the App-image style="width: 190px;max-height: 190px;clip-path: square(25px at center);"

Comment: Ok I will do that And Let you know

Comment: Yes its working But , Blue Icon on Image is moving out of that Image

Comment: Dont worry let me see

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185464/discussion-between-sumit-kumar-and-sundeep).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

so i've changed the code a bit and this is what you will need:

```
<style>

.Pad{
padding: 60px 0px;
margin-top: -300px;
}

body {
margin: 0;
}

.outer-div-for-the-imgae-icon{position:relative; display:block; height:300px; width:300px;   }

.outer-div-for-the-imgae-icon img{height:300px; width:300px; object-fit:cover;}

.outer-div-for-the-imgae-icon i{position:fixed; top:0; left:100%; font-size:40px;}

</style>

<html>
    <body>
        <div class="col-12 col-12 p-0">
            <div class="col-6 float-left">
                <div class="outer-div-for-the-imgae-icon">
                    <app-image [imagesrc]="imagePath" style="width: 190px;max-height: 190px;clip-path: square(25px at center);"
                               class="d-none d-sm-block" alt="..."></app-image>
                    <i (click)="inputFile.click()" style="color : white;left: 180px;
                                position: absolute; top: -5px; padding: 3px; background-color: rgb(0, 195, 255);
                                border-radius: 50%;font-size: 12px;"
                       class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 Pad float-right">
                    <div class="col-sm ">
                        <span class="name">
                            <b style="color: rgb(25,25,112); font-size : 15px ">{{myprofile?.FirstName}}
                                {{myprofile?.LastName}}</b>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm">
                        <span class="name">
                            <p>{{myprofile?.Role}}</p>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm">
                        <span class="name">
                            <p>{{myprofile?.Phone}} {{myprofile?.UserName}}</p>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="over" >
                <img src="https://stepupandlive.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/3d-animated-frog-image.jpg"> some text
            </div>
            <div style="padding-left: 100px;" class="col-6 float-right">
                <div class="col-12 ">
                    <div class="office-address-heading">
                        <p class="Address">Office Address</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <!-- <i style="color:grey;" class="fa fa-map-marker fa-2x mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i> -->
                <address class="mb-0 size">
                    {{myprofile?.OfficeAddress}}
                </address>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr />
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="office-address-heading">
                        <p class="Address">Communication Details</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center office-address-details ">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style ="right: 14px;">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-5 float-left">
                                <i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <a style="color: black;" href="tel:1-562-867-5309">{{myprofile?.Phone}}</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-flex1 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-7 align-items-center office-address-details float-right ">
                                <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <a style="color: black;" href="mailto:rafael.cepeda@lpl.com">{{myprofile?.Email}}</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

which you will get this result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6avne.png)

what i have changed is removing the css from the div that is responsible for the image, (bear in mind that i don't have the required files like photo's, links ect.... but this changed the image not overlapping the text.

reply if there is something wrong or if you have any questions

Comment: Hi @MLC_No_Scope , Thanks for your reply ... But I am applying Image for this div " outer-div-for-the-imgae-icon " , Please can you help me in this??

Comment: Hi @MLC_No_Scope , Thanks for your reply ... But I am applying Image for this div " outer-div-for-the-imgae-icon " , Please can you help me in this?? Please check this div " outer-div-for-the-imgae-icon "  problem is with that DIV..... I updated the code Please check that

Comment: i'm not sure what the app-image element means, but why not using <img>?

Comment: App-image means we are geeting that image from other component.. But fine not a problem please give your Solution.. problem is from this div : “ col-6 pad float right”. In this div I have given 3 attributes(Name, phone number) As you can see in that Image . So that values are overlapping with image

Comment: Okay so you want them to be separate right ?i mean the image and the text right?